# Parse txt eliminate header and footer Apache-Hop

Tags: apache-hop

I´m trying Apache HOP Desktop and I´m stuck in a pipeline where I have to clean and parse this one column txt. First eliminating header and footer then parsing according to position and lenght.

```
name:  Initial_Pos: Lenght:
N1     2            10
N2     12           24
N3     108          30
```

i´m trying to use 'Text File Input' as a transform but no luck. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The text file input transform has a wide variety of options you can use.
Under the content tab you can set the filetype to a fixed with file, add the number of header/footer lines and special things like encoding.
[text file input content tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muJsH.png)

Then under the fields tab you can set the position and length of each field it has to read.

After a bit of fiddling you should be able to extract the information you need.